# Comparing class is giving incorrect output

Tags: ios, objective-c, compare

I am using below code to check view controllers.

```
NSLog(@"addProductClicked 1===%@", self.class);

NSLog(@"addProductClicked 2===%@", [CategoriesViewController class]);

if ([self.class isKindOfClass:[CategoriesViewController class]]) {

    NSLog(@"you go it right");

} else {
    NSLog(@"you go it wrong");
}
```

The output I get is as below.

```
addProductClicked 1===CategoriesViewController
addProductClicked 2===CategoriesViewController

you go it wrong
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

---

Just to update, below is what I have defined my view controller...

```
@interface CategoriesViewController : GlobalViewController {
```

Now in `GlobalViewController` I have method where I am checking above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you want to class check should be passed in as an object, not as a class.

```
if ([self isKindOfClass:[CategoriesViewController class]]) {
    NSLog(@"you go it right");
} else {
    NSLog(@"you go it wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats is wrong comparison. You call `isKindOfClass:` on the object of that class. Something like this:

```
CategoriesViewController *obj = [[CategoriesViewController alloc] init];
[obj isKindOfClass:CategoriesViewController];
```

In your case you probably want to put a check on `self`.